# TypeError: 'accounts' object is not iterable

Tags: python, tkinter, peewee

[image]

I'm working on a script using Tkinter and the Peewee ORM. I've got:

```
db = SqliteDatabase('data.db')
introspector = Introspector.from_database(db)
models = introspector.generate_models()
cities_list = []
account_obj = models['accounts']
recordset= account_obj.select()
for r in recordset:
    city = str(r.city)
    elapsed_hours = (time.time()-int(r.datetime))/3600
    cities_list.append(str(r.city)+'-'+str(elapsed_hours))


master = tk.Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set(cities_list[0]) # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *cities_list)
w.pack()

def ok():
    print ("value is:" + variable.get())
    v_list = variable.get().split('-')
    print type(account_obj)
    recordset = account_obj.select().where(account_obj.city.contains(v_list[0])).get()
    for r in recordset:
        r.datetime=int(time.time())
        r.update()


button = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

At the second select statement:

```
recordset = account_obj.select().where(account_obj.city.contains(v_list[0])).get()
```

I'm getting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
<class 'peewee.BaseModel'>
  File "...lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1542, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "... myscript.py", line 46, in ok
    for r in recordset:
TypeError: 'accounts' object is not iterable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Generally, `get()` returns only one instance (if any). You should probably replace it by `all()` (which returns a `list` which is *iterable*) in the line: `recordset = account_obj.select().where(account_obj.city.contains(v_list[0])).get()`. Hope this makes sense since I have no experience with this framework.

Comment: recordset = account_obj.select().where(account_obj.city.contains(v_list[0])).all()
AttributeError: 'SelectQuery' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: I was afraid that this might occur. Then try removing `.get()` altogether.

Comment: Ok, that gets rid of the error but now I am stuck in a loop in the Tkinter in the button function.There is no error but the function does not return

Comment: Peewee does not use ".all()". And like previous commenter said, ".get()" returns a single instance, not a collection. Just remove the call to ".get()". Also, ".update()" isn't the correct invocation. You want .save(). Did you even read the docs? This is way wrong.

Comment: I tried save() didn't work.

Comment: The issue turned out to be that my table which I imported from a csv did not have a primary key. Once I added that, save() started working. please see http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#updating-existing-records

Comment: @user61629 Please provide that as an answer so that the question _looks_ answered as well.

Answer (score 0):

At the request of @Nae Here is my working code rearranged:

```
master = tk.Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set(cities_list[0]) # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *cities_list)
w.pack()

def ok():
    print ("value is:" + variable.get())
    master.destroy()

button = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
button.pack()

mainloop()

v_list = variable.get().split('-')
recordset = account_obj.select().where(account_obj.city.contains(v_list[0]))
for r in recordset:
    r.datetime = int(time.time())
    r.save()
```

The issue turned out to be that my table which I imported from a csv did not have a primary key. Once I added that, save() started working. please see http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#updating-existing-records